# Script issue with an array reference

Tags: google-apps-script

Please excuse the length of the post I was getting help but the person has not been online for the last week so thought I would try here to get the last few kinks out.  Thank you for any extra help.

Here is my original script.

```
function ImportDataRange() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("AM trip"); //To Sheet Name
 var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1n4**4HzvVS****RQhPHndUbn0N0nkpOE5NpO2U"); // From Spreadsheet ID
 var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName("AM trip"); // From Sheet name
 var range = sheetraw.getRange("B9:U38");
 var data = range.getValues();
 sheet.getRange("C1").setValues(data)
}

My adjusted script:-
function ImportDataRange() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('AM trip'); //To Sheet Name
 var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18h-UAy10EvANHZXLebspZsUbE2fisyEBAFnUYV9JBHs'); // From Spreadsheet ID
 var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName('AM trip'); // From Sheet name
 var range = sheetraw.getRange('B7:U38');
 var data = range.getValues();
 var lastRow = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,3).setValue(data);

}}
This takes B7 from the original spreadsheet and places it in the next blank row down and in Column C but not B7:U38, if i change setValue(data) to setValues(Data) I get the range height error.

Then below, I got from you and below the script is the error it produces:-
function ImportDataRange() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('AM trip'); //To Sheet Name
 var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18hAy10EvANHZXLebspZsUbE2fisyEBAFnUYV9JBHs'); // From Spreadsheet ID
 var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName('AM trip'); // From Sheet name
 var range = sheetraw.getRange('B7:U38');
 var data = range.getValues();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
  setValues(sheet, lastRow, 3, data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is range height should match the height of the data being input.
You will have to modify the code like so

```
function ImportDataRange() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('AM trip'); //To Sheet Name
 var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18hAy10EvANHZXLebspZsUbE2fisyEBAFnUYV9JBHs'); // From Spreadsheet ID
 var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName('AM trip'); // From Sheet name
 var range = sheetraw.getRange('B7:U38');
 var data = range.getValues();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
 sheet.getRange(lastRow,3,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)
}
```

Basically, get the length of the data array use `array.length` gives you number of rows. You find more details on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length?v=example)

Details on setValues can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues), similarly details on getRange can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Hope that helps

Comment: What if today we have 8 entries in a column (with attendant (ROW) data) but tomorrow we have 12 entries in the column with the attendant (ROW) data.

Comment: you can use [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: Thank you that sorts the issue perfectly.  It may be cheeky but if I have 5 sheets in the From spreadsheet and identical 5 sheets in the target spreadsheet how can I get the same range in the other 4 sheets to their same named counterpart in the target sheet?

Comment: How do you select the sheet named "Am Trip" in your target and destination spreadsheet?

Comment: var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('AM trip'); //To Sheet Name
 var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18hAy10EvANHZXLebspZsUbE2fisyEBAFnUYV9JBHs'); // From Spreadsheet ID
 var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName('AM trip'); // From Sheet name But not sure how to chain the other 4 sheets i have tried ('AM Trip', 'PM Trip' etc) in from and target sheet name heading or do i just repeat the same code below the previous one substituting the other spreadsheet names?

Comment: You repeat the code, substituting the name of the sheet each time.

Comment: Sorry, have now accepted the answer, will copy code and change sheet name, thank you for your help.

Comment: I have set up the code as below but only importing the first sheet, also is there a way to only need to enter the originating spreadsheet id once for the whole code instead of at each sheet section?